# How to write a map into csv in scala

Tags: scala, maps

I have a map like this

```scala
val colors = Map("red" -> "A", "azure" -> "B","Green"->"c")
```

I have this following piece of code

```scala
val file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New Text Document.csv")

val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))

for((k, v) <- colors)  
{     
  bw.write(k+", "+v+"\n") 
} 
bw.close()
```

however the op in csv file is like this

[image]

is there any way to transpose it like the op should look like this

[image]

Comment: `bw.write(map.keysIterator.mkString("", ",", "\n"))` - `bw.write(map.valuesIterator.mkString("", ",", "\n"))`